# How do I show that the ideal is not principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $S$ be the set of polynomials $p(t)$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ for which $p(1)$ is even. Is $S$ an ideal, and if so, is it principal?

I proved the ideal part. Now, I suppose the ideal $S$ is principal, i.e $S=(f(x))$, then $f(x)+2 \in S$, there exists $g(x)$ such that $f(x)+2=f(x)g(x)$. I tried to conclude this, but not able to conclude it correctly. Can anyone suggest some point for the last step?

Answer (score 2):

If $S=(f)$ then in particular $f|2$, because the constant polynomial $2$ belongs to $S$. This implies $f$ has to be a constant polynomial. $S$ is clearly not the whole ring, and so $f\notin\{1,-1\}$. So we must have $f\in\{2,-2\}$, and anyway $S=(2)$. But this is a contradiction, for example because $t+1\in S$, and this polynomial is not divisible by $2$.